# Vector dot product - determine the angle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Im having problem determining cosines. Does anyone know how to solve it? Can anyone provide some hint or full solution? 
Please Help !

> Data are the vectors $x$ and $y$, where $\| x \| = 3$, $\|y\| = 4$, and $xy =
>  2$. Determine $\| x - 2y \|$, $\| x + 3y \|$ and $cos (∡ (x - 2y, 3y + x))$.

Comment: What have *you* been able to do with it so far?

Comment: Does "$\;xy=2\;$" mean the scalar (dot) product of the vectors $\;x,y\;$ equals two?

Comment: ||x-2y|| = -5 ||x+3y||=9  cos(x+y,x+3y) = 2/((-5) * 9) <-- but teacher said its wrong way

Comment: xy => (x|y) = ||x|| * ||y|| cos (x,y)

Comment: I didn't know how to interpret the symbol $xy>=2$.

Comment: it pasted adittional sign its xy ==> (x|y)

Comment: @DaveM Perhaps you could learn something important in the next link: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This will also be useful, thanks :]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, and denoting by $\;\langle x,y\rangle\;$ the dot product of $\;x,y\;$:

$$\left\|x-2y\right\|^2=\langle x-2y,\,x-2y\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle-4\langle x,y\rangle+4\langle y,y\rangle=9-4\cdot2+4\cdot16=65$$

Do the rest, and also remember that if $\;\theta=\angle(a,b)\;$ ,then

$$\cos\theta=\frac{\langle a,b\rangle}{\left\|a\right\|\left\|b\right\|}$$

Comment: You need $-4\langle x,y \rangle$

Comment: @user160738 Good catch, thanks.

Comment: Thank you i will try with this :)

Comment: @DonAntonio But shouldn't it be that 4⟨y,y⟩ = 4 * ||4||^2  so its 65 not 17?

Comment: @DaveM True. Good catch!

Comment: @DonAntonio so is it correct that  ||x+3y|| =171 ? and cos(∡(x−2y,3y+x)) = 0.000179937 ?

Comment: my mistake ||x+3y|| = 189 right? and then cos(∡(x−2y,3y+x)) = 0.0001628002?